# List all files in specific directory in repository in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I would like to add parameter in Jenkins job that would discover files in specific folder and by ticking some of list elements let me choose only those I need. I have got main folder with two additional directories inside (/app and /tests) and from tests I would like list all files.

Do you have any ideas how to do that including 'list subversion list' ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's important when asking Jenkins questions to specify if you're working on a freestyle job, a scripted pipeline, or a declarative pipeline so that folks can help.

Comment: I have got multi configuration project

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution by my own. If you are curious then here it is:
 - install Active Choices Reactive Parameter in jenkins
 - install subversion on slave
 - add Active Choices Reactive Parameter to jenkins job and write groovy script using 'svn ls *path_to_repository*'